# How to get ChildView in expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener method?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want change child view color when expandableListView is expanded. Something like this:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                for (int i=0; i<expandableListDetail.get(
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).size(); i++){

                    String itemName = expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(i).toString();
                    Entity item = DB.Dao().getByNmae(itemName);
                    Boolean itemCheckbox = item.getCheckbox();
                    String type = item.getType();
                    View v = ?????????????? // childview
                    if (itemCheckbox==false){
                        try {
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                           
                        }
                    }else{
                        try {
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                           
                        }
                    }
                    
                }

            }
        });
```

how to get ChildView to change the color? Is there any other way?